# Container with key and sorting criteria separate

Tags: c++, stl, containers

I want to have a collection of items which are searchable based on a key (an unsigned value), but I want the elements to be sorted based on a different criteria i.e. the last accessed time (Which is part of the value).

How can I achieve this in C++? I can sort them separately on demand, but can I create the container itself such that sorting happens automatically?

Are there ready made containers (in boost) that can have similar feature built into them?

Comment: I have never tried myself, but believe you can implement a comparison function and use it with std::map. Each item could hold a date of the last time they were accessed and you sort based on this value.

Comment: A straightforward way would be to have an `std::forward_list` to store keys to elements in `std::unordered_map` dependent on how recently they were accessed, and store pointers from the values of `std::unordered_map` to the elements of the list, so that you can update access time in O(1). I'll try to patch together some code and post it.

Comment: @Brady : I want to order based on the time which is stored in the value part of the container... Is that possible? I thought I could write a comparison function based only on the key

Comment: @ArunValakottial The comparison function can do whatever it wants. I'm trying to make a mockup and I will post it as an answer

Comment: [In Boost](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html).

Comment: I have realized that std::map will not work because only the keys can be sorted. The template system does not like me for sorting by anything else lol.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably implement something of this kind, using `std::list` and `std::unordered_map` pointing to each other.

```
#include <list>
#include <unordered_map>

template <typename A>
struct Cache {
    using key = unsigned;

    struct Composite {
        Composite(A &_a, std::list<key>::iterator _it) : a(_a), it(_it) {}
        A &a;
        std::list<key>::iterator it;
    };

    std::unordered_map<key, Composite> map;
    std::list <key> list;

    void insert(key k, A &a) { // Assuming inserting contains accessing                                                                                                          
        list.emplace_front(k);
        map[k] = Composite(a, list.front());
    }

    A &operator[](key k) {
        list.erase(map[k].it);
        list.emplace_front(k);
        return map[k].a;
    }

    A &last_accessed() { // or whatever else you wish to implement                                                                                                               
        assert(!list.empty());
        return map[list.front()].a;
    }
};
```

This solution is optimized for keeping track of which element was accessed last. If you want to sort given a different attribute, you can follow a similar process but use an `std::set` to store the values with your comparison function, and then iterators to that from an `std::unordered_map` hashed with a key of your choice.

Comment: Is there a reason you used unordered_map? I was thinking something along the lines of `std::map<unsigned, std::list::iterator> with a std::list<std::pair<Type, std::map::iterator>>`. When an item is accessed it is moved to the beginning of the list and its iterator into the map is used to update the map's iterator to the item. Or better yet use an intermediary map so the actual objects are not moved around.

Comment: @BradyDean I see your point, but `std::map` has `O(log n)` access time, rather than `O(1)`